# awk で、ヘッダ付き csv から、 ヘッダでカラムたちを抜き出すには？

Tags: awk

以下のような、ヘッダ付き csv から、ヘッダを複数個、指定して、その列のみを出力したいと考えました。また、これを実現するにあたり、どこにでもある awk で実装したいと考えました。

csv 例:

```
NAME,AGE,GENDER
Jack,30,Male
Joe,25,Male
Mary,23,Female
```

実装したい関数の例:

```
cat the_csv | extract_columns AGE GENDER
# => AGE, GENDER の列だけが出力される。つまり:
# 30,Male
# 25,Male
# 23,Female
```

これは、どうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

印刷する列を抽出し、それらをループすることができます。

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","; split(cols, names)}
FNR==1 {
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {          # extract column numbers to be printed
          for (n in names) {
              if (names[n]==$i)
                  columns[i]=1
          }
   }
next
}
{for (c in columns)              # loop through columns
    st=(st ? st FS : "") $c      # pick needed to print
 print st                        # print line
 st=""
}
```

#### 例

```
$ awk -v cols="AGE,NAME" -f script.wk file
Jack,30
Joe,25
Mary,23
$ awk -v cols="AGE,GENDER" -f script.wk file
30,Male
25,Male
23,Female
```

Answer (score 1):

gawk, nawk, mawk での動作を確認していますが、mawk の `length` 関数は配列には対応していませんので `arr_length` というユーザ定義関数を追加しています。

**extract_columns**

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# mawk doesn't have the function that returns the length of an array
function arr_length(arr,    i) {
  i = 0;for (_ in arr) i++;return i
}

BEGIN {
  if (ARGC < 2) {
    print "No query strings." | "cat 1>&2"
    exit(1)
  }

  FS = OFS = ","

  # read query string
  for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) {
    col[ARGV[i]] = ""
  }

  # read header
  getline < "-"
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if ($i in col){
      ix[i] = ""
    }
  }
  if (arr_length(ix) == 0) {
    print "No matching columns." | "cat 1>&2"
    exit(1)
  }

  # query data
  while (getline r < "-") {
    split(r, ar)
    for (i=a=1;i<=arr_length(ar);i++) {
      if (i in ix) {
        $(a++) = ar[i]
      }
    }
    NF = a - 1; print
  }
}
```

---

```
$ cat the_csv | ./extract_columns AGE GENDER
30,Male
25,Male
23,Female
```